# Magento 2 Migration Tool - connection timed out

Tags: magento-2.0, magento2-migration-tool

I followed all steps to establish a connection for migration magento 1 to magento 2. When trying to migrate it gives the following error:

> [Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception]   SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection timed
>   out
>
> [PDOException]   SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection timed out

---

```
<source>
    <database host="mysqlmaster.d1.hypernode.io" name="doux" user="app" password="pwwww"/>
</source>
<destination>
    <database host="mysqlmaster.d2.hypernode.io" name="magento2" user="app" password="pwwww"/>
</destination>
```

thanks

Comment: Bart, did you find the solution? I have same issue here. Thanks

Comment: I got the same issue does anyone have any idea about it?

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, this message is not very helpful. I faced this once and my source database was out of reach.

So, one of your databases, or both, cannot be reached most likely.

If the settings you put are ok, maybe it's a firewall or VPN issue.